# Nativescript. check for android settings enabled

Tags: angular, nativescript

Could anybody help to check for android settings enabled. Particularly how to check for DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED???

Trying to do smth like this:

`Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED , 0);`

but can't get it...

or smt like this:

`android.provider.Settings.Global.getInt(android.content.ContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
import * as appModule from "tns-core-modules/application";
declare let android: any; // or better use tns-platform-declarations

const nativeApp = appModule.android.nativeApp;

let settings = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getInt(
    nativeApp.getContentResolver(),
    android.provider.Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED,
    0
);

console.log(`settings ${settings}`);
```